# How do I remove the gray border that surrounds background images?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've come across an interesting problem in the following line of code:

```
  <img style="background-image:url(Resources/bar.png); width: 300px; height: 50px;"/>
```

In Safari (at least), a gray border surrounds the 300x50px area. Adding style="border: none;" doesn't remove it. Any ideas?

Thanks.
Mike

Comment: Doesn't work. The border doesn't appear if I replace the img tag with a div tag… Is that how it is supposed to be done?

Comment: do you dynamically change the css of the page using javascript?

Comment: napster is right. you are doing it wrong. background is css property for images. look to my example for a correct image parameters

Comment: @ElzoValugi I know this is super old, but I am getting a border around my background image and I am dynamically changing it via Javascript. You are the only one that has alluded to this issue. Any ideas of how I can fix this?

Comment: @daveMac I dont remember now and without an example of what you are actually doing is difficult. Try the css thing that I posted or try to put another question with your code and put a link here to it. I will give a look to see if I can help

Comment: @ElzoValugi Here is my particular issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218370/unwanted-border-around-background-image-div

Comment: from css tricks, 1x1 base 64 transparent img `src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"`

Comment: Browsers are automatically adding these borders when no `src` is presented. @neaumusic your trick has saved me another hour of work.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

So, you have an img element that doesn't have a src attribute, but it does have a background-image style applied.

I'd say that the gray border is the 'placeholder' for where the image would be, if you'd specified a src attribute.

If you don't want a 'foreground' image, then don't use an img tag - you've already stated that changing to a div solves the problem, why not go with that solution?

Comment: Correct. I think this is it exactly. I have fixed it using div. I didn't realize img tag was only for foreground images. But yes, this is the answer as far as I can tell.

Comment: It's sad that CSS3 forces the user to have this ugly default border. That is why I try to avoid using terrible premade tags like 'img'.

Comment: HTML should be descriptive, and if you want to manage your images with CSS you shouldnt change your html...

Comment: there is a solution class for this, when adding the attribute alt and src empty the gray border will disappear.

Answer (score 26):

You can also add a blank image as a place holder:

```
img.src='data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhFAAUAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAUABQAAAIRhI+py+0Po5y02ouz3rz7rxUAOw=='
```

This should do the trick!

Comment: Or an even smaller image(GIF instead of PNG): `<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7">`

Answer (score 14):

Actually, this seems to work at least on Chrome:

```
img {
 content: "";
}
```

Comment: This does the trick (along with `display: inline-block` to keep dimensions), but it keeps empty image even if source image isn't broken...

Comment: Your combined answers is the solution for Chrome. Yet, in FF there is not only border but also broken image icon. Compatibility.... :-(

Comment: With Chome 59, the border still shows with both, but the src='data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhFAAUAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAUABQAAAIRhI+py+0Po5y02ouz3rz7rxUAOw==' hack still fixes it.

Answer (score 9):

The following will use css to set the src to a tiny transparent image which solves the src attribute issue while maintaining control from image:

`content:url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7')`

My overall approach is to define the following in my reset.css, then use a class to provide the actual image and control it. This behaves just like an img, but is entirely css controlled.

```
img {
  display: -moz-inline-box;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  *
  vertical-align: auto;
  font: 0/0 serif;
  text-shadow: none;
  color: transparent;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img:not([src]) {
    content:             url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7');
}

.myuniqueimage {
    background-image: url('../images/foobar.png');
    height: 240px;
}
```

Thanks to +programming_historian and +binnyb for the data:image tip

Answer (score 3):

try `<img border="0" />`

That should do the trick.

EDIT

Sorry I see you are doing something very wrong.. you are setting a background image on a img tag.. that doesn't really make sense...

instead of a imagetag use a

`<div style="background-image: url(Resources/bar.png);"></div>`

or if it is a image you want in that area use a

```
<img src="Resources/bar.png" border="0" Width="500px" Height="300" />
```

Answer (score 2):

img tags need a src attribute.

e.g.,

```
<img src="Resources/bar.png" alt="bar" width="300" height="50" />
```

But img is only for inline (foreground) images. If you actually want the image to be a background of something, you need to apply the style to the actual element you want it to be the background of:

```
<div style="background-image:url(Resources/bar.png);">...</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried setting the border to 0px?

EDIT: Yes, you are meant to have background images in the css of another class. Doing it in div or in the body tag (depending what your trying to do) will work. It also stops the background image being a element in itself which would screw the flow of the elements on the page and mess your positioning up.

```
<div class="myDivClass">content to go on TOP of the background image</div>
```

CSS:

```
.myDiVClass
{
background: url(Resources/bar.png)  no-repeat;
width: 300px; 
height: 50px;
}
```

or

```
 <div class="myDivClass" style="background: url(Resources/bar.png)  no-repeat; width: 300px; height: 50px;">content to go on TOP of the background image</div>
```

It's best to keep CSS seperate as it otherwise defeats part of the point though.

Comment: Yea. Doesn't work. It looks like a border but it seems to act like something else.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where my initial HTML had an IMAGE tag with no source.  My Javascript determined which image to show.  However before the image was loaded the user saw the placeholder box.

```
<img id="myImage">
```

My fix was to update the initial image tag CSS to

```
#myImage {
  display:none;
}
```

And then used a JQuery to show it once its content was loaded.

```
$('#myImage')
.attr('src', "/img/" + dynamicImage + '.png')
.fadeTo(500, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this instead of background-image:

```
background: url(Resources/bar.png) no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

if is happening only in Safari and not in other browsers try to reset the browser CSS using something like [YUI CSS RESET](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/cssreset/)

The correct way it would be to separate the css from code and to have a CSS class for the image.

```
<img src='whatever.png' alt='whatever' class='className' />
```

and in the css to define what className looks like.
,className {border:0;}

Comment: Didn't check other browsers, but I think I just have to use the div tag. That fixes is, but I thought an img tag was how it should be done…

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it worked for me(on chrome and Safari). That was not the border but the shadow, so please add this line to the tag:

```
{-webkit-box-shadow:none;}
```

Hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I found this useful..

In the case that your `Resources/bar.png` is a foreground image in the form of a sprite, it makes sense to use an `img` tag rather than a `div`.  When you do this it can help to have a 1px transparent image file which you use for the `src` attribute, then set the background image  as you do here e.g.

```
    <img src="transparent.png" style="background: url(sprite.png) x y" />
```

Here you set `x` and `y` to be the pixel position on the sprite that you want the image to start at.  This technique is also explained at: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Of course the downside of this is that there is an extra request, but it you're always using the same transparent image for you sprites it's not a massive deal.

Comment: this kind of worked for me, transparent.png, background-image, set height and width so the image is clipped (that was my need) and the shadow went away

Answer (score 0):

add an empty **src=""** to your image component if your using as a background-image in css the square will disappear

```
<image class=${styles.moneyIcon} src="" ></image>
```