# Unwanted border around background image div

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile-safari, background-image

I am getting a slight line or border around my background image. I am dynamically changing the height of the parent div via javascript so that the inner div (which has the background image set) will "stick" to the bottom of the window.

No line appears on the desktop browsers, but on the mobile browser after the script runs, there is usually a thin border around it:

[image]

The border is on the left and the way it should be is on the right. Any suggestions?

This is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function layoutHandler(){
    if(window.innerHeight > 1061){
    var newsize = 150 + (window.innerHeight - 1061);

        document.getElementById("footerwrapper").style.height = newsize+'px';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("footerwrapper").style.height = '150px';
    }
}
window.onload = layoutHandler;

window.onresize = layoutHandler;
layoutHandler();
</script>
```

And then the inner div is setup like so:

```
#inner {
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 150px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(Images/grad.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

**Edit:**
Okay, after testing this a bit more I narrowed down when it happens. (This might get frustratingly specific) It happens most noticeably on the iPad in portrait mode. I turned off the "repeat-x" and it goes away completely. That led me to try a much wider background image which would not be repeating within the width of the iPad and it took away this issue. Any ideas why the heck this is happening?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting `border: 0;` in the css?

Comment: Yes, it has no effect.

Comment: Is the grad.png image 150px? maybe make it a bit taller than it needs to be at the top.

Comment: @markle976 I'll try that. It is 150px right now.

Comment: What's the `background-color` of your `footerwrapper` (which I assume the `#inner` is inside of)? Could it be that the height is calculating to `> 150px` from your script and showing the background of the `footerwrapper`? Some further html and css for the whole structure it is nested in might help to solve it.

Comment: @ScottS All background colors are set to #FFF

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and removing `repeat-x` solved it. I think it is bug of phone browsers.