# gray border appearing bug in chrome

Tags: html, css

I have applied the following html

```
<input type="image" value="Search" class="button" src="" onclick="this.form.searchword.focus();">
```

and this is the css...

```
#header form .button
{
    /*border:solid 1px #999;*/
    background:#664335 url(../images/btn-search.jpg) no-repeat ;
    /*color:#fff;*/
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    width: 16px;
    height: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border: none;

}
```

I tried by removing the width and height and setting a padding value to it but no-success for this. As I searched different questions, I came to know that if src attribute is not applied then border will appear. But in my case the markup I can't edit, so is there any method to remove that bug.

Anyway I solved it by changing type image to button with jquery.

Comment: I know it is not much of an answer,but why are you trying to make the `src` attribute empty? An empty `src` attribute is not allowed in the `image button`s,so your code has the bug,not chrome!!!(chrome is just trying to fix the bug!)

Comment: Your HTML is invalid so it's never going to work correctly. How can an image not be an image? If you want to add images in your CSS, use a div not an img tag.

Comment: Why can't you access the `src` attribute in your `<input type="image"> element?

Comment: Possibly Duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073015/how-do-i-remove-the-gray-border-that-surrounds-background-images

Comment: @C-Link have you tried `outline:0`?

Comment: @Vucko yeah I've tried that too..

Comment: If I understand you, you say you can't edit change the HTML for the input line but you can update the CSS, is this the case?

Comment: @C-Link `<input type="image" value="Search" class="button" src="templates/beez5/images/btn-search.jpg" onclick="this.form.searchword.focus();">` works? Why not it use like this?

Answer (score 0):

This questing has been asked more than one time, and the best posible solution to this is just to use `type="submit"` instead of `type="image"`and just style it in CSS as you like

P.S. `type="image"` will not work in chrome as you want, try finding another way for your code, because that border is place holder for an error image like in IE widely known red cross in white box, its just there, you may try adding image that has "Search" written on it or maybe add 1x1 px transparent image there, but thats all.

Comment: by bad, will look for something else

Answer (score 0):

Apply CSS:

```
#header form .button {
border: solid 1px #999;
background: #664335 url(../images/btn-search.jpg) no-repeat;
color: #fff;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 0;
width: 16px;
height: 20px;
vertical-align: middle;
background-color: transparent !important;


// delete this
border: none;


}
```