# Strange line before and after background in Android

Tags: android, html, css

In mobile browsers (Google Chrome v41.0.2272.96 and default Android browser) I see thin line before and after backgrounds.

For example:

```
.header {
    padding: 82px 0 51px 0;
    background: #fff url('http://s1.postimg.org/mf583o3qz/wave.png') 0 0 repeat-x;
}
```

Here is test: http://jsfiddle.net/matoni555/gy58jfjo/

Here is screenshot what I see: http://postimg.org/image/ncdxz6el9/

Why there are these strange lines before and after backgrounds?

Comment: use background color as transparent  `background: transparent url('http://s1.postimg.org/mf583o3qz/wave.png') 0 0 repeat-x;`

Comment: @TamilSelvan I need white background in header. In footer I use transparent background and there is problem too.

Comment: try `.header { outline: 0; ..}`

Comment: @TamilSelvan I tried it, but nothing changed. You can see it on my jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an exact answer, but there are lots of ideas on this page: [How do I remove the gray border that surrounds background images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073015/how-do-i-remove-the-gray-border-that-surrounds-background-images)

Hopefully something there will get you unstuck.

Comment: I looked at this page, but there is problem with img tag. I tried to add `-webkit-box-shadow: none` but it does not work.