# How to remove outline of hover image in html

Tags: html, css, web

I'm trying to remove gray color outline of images. 
I saw that that outline means error because image tags don't have source properties.
but if i add  `src="image.jpg"`,  hovering doesn't work.

how to fix it? so confused....

this is my code

```css
#item1 {
  background-image: url('cushion01.jpg');
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
#item1:hover {
  background-image: url('cushion-01.jpeg');
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="secondary__item" style="width: 100%; height : 850px;">
  <ul class="item-images">
    <li class="item-image">
      <img class="item" id="item1"  src="image.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li class="item-image">
      <img class="item" id="item2" />
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="item-images">
    <li class="item-image">
      <img class="item" id="item3" />
    </li>
    <li class="item-image">
      <img class="item" id="item4" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: There is a typo error in css. remove space before hover.. #item1:hover

Comment: Do you want to set `background-image` to `img` tag? Strange

Comment: And `<img>` tag must hava a `src` attribute its better to use a `<div>` tag

Comment: possible of duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073015/how-do-i-remove-the-gray-border-that-surrounds-background-images

Comment: solved! i changed image tag to div tag :D! i wanted to put some images so i used img tag. and it caused problem :0... thx for replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange thing is that you are trying to set background to `<img>` tag. If I were you I'd use `<div>` instead. Then It would be very simple:

HTML:

```
    <div class= "secondary__item" style="width: 100%; height : 850px;">
        <ul class="item-images">
        <li class="item-image"><div class="item"  id="item1" ></div></li>
            <li class="item-image"><div class="item"  id="item2" ></div></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="item-images">
            <li class="item-image"><div class="item"  id="item3" ></div></li>
            <li class="item-image"><div class="item"  id="item4" ></div></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.item {
height:300px;
width :300px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size : cover;

/*you can remove it*/
border: 1px solid;
}
.item:hover {
background-image: url('http://shushi168.com/data/out/114/36276270-image.png');
height:300px;
width :300px;
}
```

Here is a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7kzu5qcy/2/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried instead of using IDs to use the main identifier?

like...

```
.item-image IMG {
 border:none;
}
```

Comment: Considering you're using this to set a background-image and no foreground image, why don't you simply change the IMG tags to DIVS instead, do the same job, and there's no placeholder border.

Answer (score 0):

Place this in your image tag

```
alt=""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
item1:hover {
    border: none !important;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a simple hack using `margin` & `overflow` property of CSS.

Something like this:

```
/* Image Container (Parent) */
.item-image {
  width: 298px;
  height: 298px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Image (Child) */    
.item-image img {
  margin: -1px;
  background: #eee; /* To show the area covered by image */
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below (*I've applied background color to image to show the image area*):

```css
#item1 {
  background-image: url('cushion01.jpg');
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
#item1:hover {
  background-image: url('cushion-01.jpeg');
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.item-image {
  width: 298px;
  height: 298px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item-image img {
  margin: -1px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="secondary__item" style="width: 100%; height : 850px;">
  <ul class="item-images">
    <li class="item-image">
      <img class="item" id="item1"  src="image.jpg" />
    </li>
    <li class="item-image">
      <img class="item" id="item2" />
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="item-images">
    <li class="item-image">
      <img class="item" id="item3" />
    </li>
    <li class="item-image">
      <img class="item" id="item4" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I see the answer to this is given in [chrome/safari display border around image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743127/chrome-safari-display-border-around-image).

```
The reason cited is <img> tag does not have proper value in src attribute.
```